# How to compare files with Boost.Test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I've two files that I need to compare.
I would use something like this

```
BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(filename1, filename2);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html) to compare file contents.

Code sample:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test )
{
    std::ifstream ifs1("data1.txt");
    std::ifstream ifs2("data2.txt");

    std::istream_iterator<char> b1(ifs1), e1;
    std::istream_iterator<char> b2(ifs2), e2;

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(b1, e1, b2, e2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after reading ForEveR answer, I did it nearly ths way. But using binary mode to open the files std::ifstream ifs1("data1.txt", std::ios::binary);

Comment: Don't forget to set noskipws flag => std::noskipws(ifs1), to discard skipping of whitespace in binary files, otherwise the iterator will skip any whitespaces and \t and \n will be skipped but files are still different.

Comment: e1 and e2 are indicating the end of the iteration. Wouldn't it be better to use the begin() and end() methods of the iterator!?
I am using something like this (with std::vector<string>):
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(b1.begin(), b1.end(), b2.begin(), b2.end());

Comment: e1 and e2 are default constructed [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), which gives you an "end of stream" iterator.  Therefore, they are the end iterators that indicate the stream is exhausted.  `vector` is a collection that provides `begin` and `end` methods returning iterators (although C++11 style now would prefer using global `std::begin` free functions passed the container), whereas `istream_iterator` is an iterator adapter that doesn't have `begin` and `end` methods returning an iterator because they *are* iterators.

Answer (score 3):

Files? Read both and compare contents.

Comment: I don't see how this comes even close to answering the question. It's simply dismissive and unhelpful

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the hashes of the two files. 
Examples of using openssl library to calculate hashes are plenty.

Comment: Different content may result into same hash so after hach comparision whole comparision still needed. To calculate hash file must be read through. So unless the hash is a feature of FS, hash compare would not make a benefit.